# Adding ftp records as A or CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it better to use a A record or CNAME record for FTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FTP doesn't care. In the end as long as it points to an IP address it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

For Future Beeing its better to use an CNAME so when you change the Server or the IP Address you only need the Change the A-Record for the IP Adress or the Cname if you switch servers.

CNAME ftp.mycompany.com server1.mycompany.com
A server1.mycompany.com 123.123.123.123